# Staggered Gridview item disappear when scrolling

Tags: flutter, gridview, staggered-gridview

I have some question on the latest `flutter_staggered_grid_view` package. Can anyone help me please?

1. the item in gridview below will disappear when scrolling

```
SliverGrid(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) {
              return Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.teal[100 * (index % 9)],
                child: Text('grid item $index'),
              );
            },
            childCount: 10,
          ),
          gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
            crossAxisCount: 10,
            mainAxisSpacing: 15,
            crossAxisSpacing: 15,
            pattern: [
              QuiltedGridTile(9, 5),
              QuiltedGridTile(8, 5),
              QuiltedGridTile(9, 5),
              QuiltedGridTile(8, 5),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

I have seen some error appeared but can't find any hint or solution

```
package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adapter.dart': Failed assertion: line 506 pos 12: 'childCount >= leadingGarbage + trailingGarbage': is not true

AND 

package: flutter/src/rendering/sliver_grid.dart': Failed assertion: line 679 pos 12: 'targetLastIndex == null || lastIndex <= targetLastIndex': is not true
```

2. Another question is does the package version `0.6.1` not supported dynamic content height anymore? Is there any example can refer?